# Merging a groupby object with another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with repesenting the sales of an item:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2], 'week': [1,2,2,3,1,3], 'quantity': [1,2,4,3,2,2]}
df_sales = pd.DataFrame(data)
 >>> df_sales
   id  week  quantity
0   1     1         1
1   1     2         2
2   1     3         3
3   2     1         2
4   2     3         2
```

I have another data frame that represents the available weeks:

```
data = {'week': [1,2,3]}
df_week = pd.DataFrame(data)
 >>> df_week
   week
0     1
1     2
2     3
```

I want to `groupby` the  `id` and the `week` and compute the mean, which I do as follows:

```
df = df_sales.groupby(by=['id', 'week'], as_index=False).mean()
 >>> df
   id  week  quantity
0   1     1         1
1   1     2         3
2   1     3         3
3   2     1         2
4   2     3         2
```

However, I want to fill the missing week values (present in `df_week`) with `0`, such that the output is:

```
 >>> df
   id  week  quantity
0   1     1         1
1   1     2         3
2   1     3         3
3   2     1         2
4   2     2         0
4   2     3         2
```

Is it possible to `merge` the `groupby` with the `df_week` data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `reindex` after `groupby`

```
# group and aggregate
df  = df_sales.groupby(['id', 'week']).mean()

# define new MultiIndex
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], df_week['week']])

# reindex with fill_value=0
df  = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(df)

   id  week  quantity
0   1     1         1
1   1     2         3
2   1     3         3
3   2     1         2
4   2     2         0
5   2     3         2
```

Comment: I get the following error on `idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], df_week['week']])`:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'levels'

Comment: ... using pandas version 1.1.4

Comment: Remove `as_index` optional keyword argument. We have to use `df  = df_sales.groupby(['id', 'week']).mean()`

Comment: ‍♂️ that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Since all unique id and week combinations are needed in the result, one way is to first prepare a combinations frame with `pd.merge` passed `how="cross"`:

```
combs = pd.merge(df_sales.id.drop_duplicates(), df_week.week, how="cross")
```

or for versions below 1.2

```
combs = pd.merge(df_sales.id.drop_duplicates().to_frame().assign(key=1),
                 df_week.week.to_frame().assign(key=1), on="key").drop(columns="key")
```

which gives

```
>>> combs

   id  week
0   1     1
1   1     2
2   1     3
3   2     1
4   2     2
5   2     3
```

Now we can left merge this with `df` that has the means filling `NaN`s with 0:

```
result = combs.merge(df, how="left", on=["id", "week"]).fillna(0, downcast="infer")
```

where `downcast` is to go back to integers from float type because of `NaN`(s) that appeared in the intermediate step,

to get

```
>>> result

   id  week  quantity
0   1     1         1
1   1     2         3
2   1     3         3
3   2     1         2
4   2     2         0
5   2     3         2
```

Comment: I get the following error on `combs = pd.merge(df_sales.id.drop_duplicates(), df_week.week, how="cross")`:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    "No common columns to perform merge on. "
pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: @alex_lewis `how="cross"` is for 1.2+ so probably version difference issue. I added a workaround that performs the same operation... (but it looks complicated and you seem to have found a solution so that's good!)